# sagmaker deploy() model gives error exec: "serve": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I have fitted a model succefully in Sagemaker with `classifier.fit()`, I have got success message saying that `Finished saving the model.Finished training the model. Script Status - Finished`

Now, I tried to deploy the model (make endpoint with the following code.

```
classifier.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m4.4xlarge')
```

It initially gave me error.

> Error hosting endpoint
> keras-seq-modelling2021-11-2021-01-07-11-26-56-705: Failed. Reason:
> The primary container for production variant AllTraffic did not pass
> the ping health check. Please check CloudWatch logs for this
> endpoint..

When I looked in logs (cloud watch log stream), It is giving following error.

> exec: "serve": executable file not found in $PATH

I know it is relating to making some file executable with granting right permision in some docker container, but the point is that it should be handled by sagemaker and all we need to do according to tutorial is `model.deploy()`

Am I doing something wrong. Any idea how to resolved this.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem using a Huggingface estimator. The only help I've found is related to using custom Docker images for training / inference - but I'm using the off-the-shelf Huggingface containers. I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my model that manifests as this sort of error

Comment: @LaserJesus, do you have serve.py file with required functionality and executable permissions?

Comment: I do not, I was able to get the sample here working https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/sagemaker/02_getting_started_tensorflow/sagemaker-notebook.ipynb    but when I changed the train script to add some extra layers to the model I started getting the serve error. I can load the trained model directly with TF in the notebook and perform inference, but deploying as an endpoint, as shown in the link here, gives me this serve error. I created an issue here with some more details https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-huggingface-inference-toolkit/issues/45

Comment: I am having the same error. Were you guys able to resolve this?